# What would be the methods of a bi-comonad?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, comonad, bifunctor

While musing what more useful standard class to suggest [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40833245/745903)

```
class Coordinate c where
  createCoordinate :: x -> y -> c x y
  getFirst :: c x y -> x
  getSecond :: c x y -> y
  addCoordinates :: (Num x, Num y) => c x y -> c x y -> c x y
```

it occured me that instead of something [`VectorSpace`-y](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.4/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#t:VectorSpace) or [`R2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.5/docs/Linear-V2.html#t:R2), a rather more general beast might lurk here: a `Type -> Type -> Type` whose two contained types can both be extracted. Hm, perhaps they can be *[`extract`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5/docs/Control-Comonad.html#v:extract)ed*?

Turns out neither the `comonad` nor [`bifunctors`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors) package contains something called `Bicomonad`. Question is, would such a class even make sense, category-theoretically? Unlike `Bimonad` (which also isn't defined, and I couldn't really see how might look), a naïve definition seems plausible:

```
class Bifunctor c => Bicomonad c where
  fst :: c x y -> x
  snd :: c x y -> y
  bidup :: c x y -> c (c x y) (c x y)
```

probably with the laws

```
fst . bidup ≡ id
snd . bidup ≡ id
bimap fst snd . bidup ≡ id
bimap bidup bidup . bidup ≡ bidup . bidup
```

but I find it disquieting that both fields of the result of `bidup` contain the same type, and there are quite a number of other, perhaps “better” conceivable signatures.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not an answer, but: A (co)monad is just a (co)monoid (with functor composition as the tensor product) in the category of **endo**functors, right? Haskell bifunctors aren't endofunctors. So I'm not sure what a real bi(co)monad would look like, or even if it makes sense to build such a thing on top of bifunctors. But perhaps there's still something useful that looks "kinda like" a bicomonad, so it's still an interesting question.

Comment: Also not an answer, but I come from the math side. For us, a bimonad is a a comonoidal monad, i.e. it is a monad on a monoidal category whose category of modules is again monoidal category. (Recall that modules over an algebra form a monoidal category iff the algebra is a bialgebra).
Likewise, a bicomonad is a monoidal comonad.

Comment: @JoBe very interesting! Could you elaborate that as an answer in math notation?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but for `Bimonad`, how about this?

```
class Biapplicative p => Bimonad p where
  (>>==) :: p a b -> (a -> b -> p c d) -> p c d

biap :: Bimonad p => p (a -> b) (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
biap p q = p >>== \ab cd -> q >>== \a c -> bipure (ab a) (cd c)

instance Bimonad (,) where
  (a,b) >>== f = f a b
```

I don't know if this is categorically right/interesting, or even remotely useful, but it smells right from a Haskell perspective. Does it match your `Bicomonad` or something similar?

Comment: Not sure; this looks a lot like the ordinary `Monad` restricted to tuple arguments (which are then curried).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Agreed. I do wonder, though, if/how your bicomonad differs from a comonad restricted to tuple arguments.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, isn't that almost true of `Biapplicative` as well (if you exclude boring functors like `Const`)?

Comment: @dfeuer, I consider `Const` one of the more important applicatives, if you're in the business of composing them which is what applicatives are good at.  Just sayin...